# Ansible AWX - write a local file

Tags: ansible-awx

I'm running ansible AWX in minikube and I could use some assistance in understanding how to write a file to AWXcontaner. My goal is to use a survey to create a template. This template would be written to the file system and pushed to a git repo for retention. Writing a file to AWX was a first test.

I'm very new to awx and minikube but the containers seems to be running fine but when I try a simple write playbook, the file is not written. The task shows "changed".

In an effort to troubleshoot I attempted to create a persistent volume but the results are the same. I'd appreciate any assistance.

playbook

```
---
- name: demonstrate using surveys with templates
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  become: false

tasks:
 - name: Creating a file with content
    copy:
      dest: "testOne.conf"
      content: "this is a test"
```

playbook execution in awx

```
PLAY [demonstrate using surveys with templates] ********************************
TASK [Creating a file with content] ********************************************
changed: [localhost]
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```
~$ kubectl get pods
NAME                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ansible-awx-dbc6f6b74-x7sv2     4/4     Running   0          3h9m
ansible-awx-postgres-0          1/1     Running   0          3h9m
awx-operator-69c646c48f-dd5dk   1/1     Running   0          3h10m
```

I've made a persistent volume

```
$ kubectl get pv
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                     STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-0a54c0b1-33b7-449a-993c-0934aac5985a   1Gi        RWX            Delete           Bound    default/awx-pvc2                          standard                3h10m
pvc-539dfe9b-3271-4697-a101-c1fa45daae6d   8Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    default/postgres-ansible-awx-postgres-0   standard                3h9m
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: awx-pvc2
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

```
apiVersion: awx.ansible.com/v1beta1
kind: AWX
metadata:
  name: ansible-awx
spec:
  service_type: nodeport
  ingress_type: none
  hostname: ansible-awx.example.com
  projects_existing_claim: awx-pvc2
  projects_persistence: true
  extra_volumes: | 
    - name: "data-vol"
      hostPath: 
        path: "/var/lib/awx"
        type: Directory 
  task_extra_volume_mounts: | 
    - name: "data-vol" 
      mountPath: "/data"
```